# Posts says they are uncategorized but they are not

Tags: categories

With the latest WP Update it seems to be a bug in posts categories.
Every posts says, in the frontend, that is uncategorized. Even if you go to every post it says “-” in the category column.

BUT category filters are working, and if you go to categories in backoffice you’ll see posts correctly counted, and if you go to the category in frontend you’ll see the posts. Even if you try to edit the post you’ll see that the category is correctly checked.

But for some reasons in backoffice (in the posts section) and in the post itself in the frontend, it says is uncategorized.

How can we solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Switch to a default theme, disable all plugins and enable them one by one checking what happens. There is nothing in common with WordPress update.

Comment: Hello. I switched to the default theme but nothing changed. I also noticed that i don't have the "uncategorized" category in my backend, even if the frontend says there is.

Comment: Are you able to acquire written information? Are all plugins disabled? It's impossible to have a non-categorized post, because when not assigned to a category, it automatically, by default, becomes "Uncategorized".